# Why is the electromagnetic spectrum only 1D?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, frequency, spectroscopy

The electromagnetic spectrum is described with wavelengths from `Gamma rays` to `Extremely low frequency`. But as far as I know, photons are waving on electro and magnetic fields too. Why is the electromagnetic spectrum not 2D then?

Comment: Why stop at 2D, the fields are perpendicular, and **photons are waving** is confusing to me, since you also mention electric fields.

Comment: it is useful to characterize electromagnetic waves by their wavelength or frequency (though this is not the unique property that specifies them).  The magnetic field is not independent of the electric field, so there is no need to specify both.

Comment: Could you please explain the downvotes?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I have no idea what you mean by 1D and 2D in the context of the electromagnetic spectrum.

Comment: If there is one independent variable, then it is a 1D scalar. If there are two, it's 2D. But now I know, that electronic and magnetic fields are not independent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The EM spectrum compares electromagnetic radiation by frequency. Although there are other physical quantities used to measure EM radiation (such as intensity and polarization), its properties depend on its frequency or wavelength more than any other quantity. When only one physical quantity is being used to compare EMR, the classification which results is 1D.

This frequency is the same for the electric (E) and the magnetic (M) fields in the EM radiation. They both oscillate at the same frequency. Also, the strength of the magnetic field is always proportional to the strength of the electric field. So it is not necessary to plot electric quantities on one axis and magnetic quantities (magnetic frequency or magnetic field strength) on another.

Comment: Does intensity means, that how many photons will hit a given surface under a specified time?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but it also depends on frequency, which determines how much energy each photon has.

Answer (score 2):

Frequency is not describing only the magnetic or electric components of an EM wave, it is describing *both* the electric and magnetic  components of the wave.  They have identical frequency and amplitude.  So in a way it is 2-D as you describe.

In a way, the electric and magnetic components are opposites. Electric currents produce magnetic fields and vice versa. In an Electromagnetic wave, when the electric component is "0" (crosses the x-axis) the magnetic component is zero. When the magnetic component is "1", the electric component is also 1.  You could not have a case where their values were unequal (in magnitude) and not orthogonal. Therefore to describe one is to describe both, because we assume they are orthogonal by definition/necessity.

Answer (score 1):

To address this part of the question:

> But as far as I know, photons are waving on electro and magnetic fields too. Why is the electromagnetic spectrum not 2D then?

Photons are zero mass [elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) and are characterized only by their energy and spin . The are described by a complex wavefunction which carries the information of the fields and the frequency, but is not measurable at the single photon level, which happens with the complex conjugate square of the wavefunction. In a confluence of photons that make up a light beam these individual wave functions build up the classical electromagnetic wave, as illustrated [in this link](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html).